# VBA named ranges counting higher than actual

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I have a master file that exports various reports, however as I copy entire sheets out (to keep formatting etc) it carries Named Ranges with it.

I need to delete these to break all links, stripped out version like so:

```
Sub buildreport()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook
    'various things
        If .Names.Count > 0 Then
            For Each Name In .Names
                Name.Delete
            Next Name
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

If I break on the `If .Names.Count > 0 Then` then I can see when hovering the count is showing as 6, however the Name Manager for the `activesheet` only has 2 Names.

Does `Names.Count` count more than just named ranges?

**EDIT**

Out of curiosity I ran the following

```
With ActiveWorkbook
    For Each Name In .Names
        Debug.Print Name
    Next Name
End With
```

which produced this

```
='GTM Roles'!$A$2:$BF$1387
=#NAME?
=#NAME?
=#NAME?
=OFFSET('[GRT MASTER mini.xlsm]All Roles'!$A$2, 0, 0, COUNTA('[GRT MASTER mini.xlsm]All Roles'!$A:$A)-1, COUNTA('[GRT MASTER mini.xlsm]All Roles'!$2:$2))
='[GRT MASTER mini.xlsm]index'!$I$2:$I$10
```

No idea what these `=#NAME?` names are, or even where they are, as they are not showing in the name manager, and throws an error that the syntax isn't correct when it tries to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting named ranges or anything from a collection is usually done with index and reversed count:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim cnt     As Long

    For cnt = ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count To 1 Step -1
        Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Names.Item(cnt).Name
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Item(cnt).Delete
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

The reason is that collections are objects like the mafia in a way - everyone knows just the next one, thus if you delete the current one with a for-each loop, you will break the collection.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will use this method moving forth, however the syntax error remains, cannot find these mythical names, nor allowed to delete them.